# NReco CustomWkHtmlArgs bearer token

Tags: javascript, c#, wkhtmltopdf, nreco

Working with NReco.PdfGenerator.HtmltoPdfConverter and recently implemented OAuth with Bearer tokens. After implementing and securing my ApiControllers the converter started throwing the following error.

*WkHtmlToPdfException: Exit with code 1 due to network error: AuthenticationRequiredError (exit code: 1)*

After some snooping I discovered I could add custom header parameters and so I grabbed the bearer token and appended it to the *CustomWkHtmlArgs*

This is what I have to far.

```
        htmlToPdf.CustomWkHtmlArgs = "-L 0mm -R 0mm -T 5mm -B 0mm --javascript-delay 3000";

        FileHandlingModule.deleteFile(savePath);

        //Get Auth Token
        var accessToken = "Bearer " + Request.Headers.Authorization.Parameter;

        htmlToPdf.CustomWkHtmlArgs += " --custom-header Authorization: " + accessToken;
        htmlToPdf.GeneratePdfFromFile(purl, null, savePath);
```

This is what the *CustomWkHtmlArgs* this is what the args string look like.

*-L 0mm -R 0mm -T 5mm -B 0mm --javascript-delay 3000 --custom-header Authorization: Bearer
    YHE7HJEh_Hk0wazErUK6DIGcCG7-GRDHBEWRA-ju9hewqPk9cjY3zH5MT....*

The token has been shortened for brevity. I've tried removing the colon and I still get the AuthRequiredError. Is anyone familiar with passing header auth tokens?

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to pass header value in quotes:

```
htmlToPdf.CustomWkHtmlArgs += " --custom-header \"Authorization\" \"" + accessToken + "\"";
```

If this header is needed to access page resources (images, css, ajax calls) option "--custom-header-propagation" should be specified too.

BTW, have you tried your to test your custom header with wkhtmltopdf from the command line? Also, you can handle `htmlToPdf.LogReceived` event and get wkhtmltopdf console log output - it might be useful for debug purposes.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the command line. That helped expedite the troubleshooting process.

Two things to note. Wrap the token in quotes, not the entire http header parameter 

'            htmlToPdf.CustomWkHtmlArgs += " --custom-header Authorization \"" + accessToken + "\"";'

If page the contains additional AJAX calls that are secured you'll also need to add the switch _--custom-header-propagation_ . This instructs wkhtmltopdf to add the header object to each subsequent call.